# Error performing 'scroll RecyclerView to: holder with view: with text:--Getting error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am using Recycler View and running a test file on it in Android Studio.

But i am getting an error when test file reaches this line

```
        onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.itemList)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollTo(withText("And a large, silver "+choice2)));
```

The error being displayed is

> androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'scroll RecyclerView to: holder with view: with text: is "And a large, silver CAT"' on view 'with id is cs.bham.ac.uk.wk12lh:id/itemList'.
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Found 0 items matching holder with view: with text: is "And a large, silver CAT", but position -1 was requested.

Kindly guide what i am doing wrong or how to get it right.

Comment: I'm having the same problem any luck finding an answer?

Comment: Yes Shawn, the problem was solved. It was not a recycler view issue, but the issue was with the test code that was checking the item of recyclerview.

Answer (score 5):

Change from this

```
 onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.itemList)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollTo(withText("And a large, silver "+choice2)));
```

to this

```
onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.itemList))
    .perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollTo(hasDescendant(withText("And a large, silver "+choice2))));
```